# Get column value by row number SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I have a transaction log, and there was a transaction on this log that is incorrect.

```
transaction    Price   balance
-------------------------------
    121          50      -50
    122         100        0
    123          50      100
    124          50      250
```

In this example, the value of transactionPrice row 122 is incorrect. I inserted a record to debit the amount back to the account with the correct total, but our system is now throwing the whole account out of balance as a result. Having deleted the insert, I now need to update all of the records so that they are correct, and I have a question.

Instead of going through and manually doing math for each record and manually creating update statements, I'm trying to create a text generator with the correct values, but I'm having problems with the "total" or "currentvalue".

Here's the problem simply stated. `THIS` record `transactionPrice = 150.00` and the `balance` after the transaction is `500`. AFTER this transaction, to `update` the NEXT `transaction` I need the PREVIOUS transactions value. I need to get that 500 so I can subtract the transactions value from the `CURRENT balance` from a previous transaction.

```
650 - 150 = 500
500 - 125 = 375
```

How do I get 500 from the previous record? **(note: this orders by desc, so "previous" goes up by `ROW_NUMBER()`, 129 comes before 128 before 127 chronologically)**

I can't use `Lag(....)`, and I've tried the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(....)` approach, but I can't seem to get the actual contents of the row, just the number itself.

Example of my statement. We are looking at `SET Balance = ' + CAST(...)`

```
SELECT 
    'UPDATE table
     SET transactionPrice = ' + CAST(@CorrectPrice as nvarchar(50)) + ', SET Balance = ' + CAST(Balance as nvarchar(50)) + '
     WHERE UsageId = ' + CAST(c.UsageId as nvarchar(50)) as 'UpdateQueriesToRun' 
FROM
    table
WHERE 
    ContractId = @ContractID 
    AND DateActive IN (SELECT DateActive
                       FROM table
                       WHERE ContractId = @ContractID)
ORDER BY 
    DateActive DESC
```

Pseudocode version of what I need

```
SELECT 
    'SET Balance = ' + CAST((PREVIOUS_ROW.BALANCE - @CorrectPrice) as nvarchar(50)) + '
        WHERE ID = ' + CAST(ID as nvarchar(50)) as 'INSTRUCTIONS' 
FROM
    table
```

Comment: you can use `SUM(Price) OVER (Order by transaction)` to get  running total and just subtract the current price from this to get the previous balance. `(SUM(Price) OVER (Order by transaction) - Price)`

Comment: Can you flesh out this example. .I'm trying what you're saying and i'm getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the `lag` function in SQL Server 2008. There are a few examples out there, here is the best article I have found on the topic.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/

Comment: I've tried this, and yes it works, but not for my particular issue where I need to store and perform manipulation on the data. thanks.